# JQuerys inArray Confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I trying to create a validation method to ensure that the users input value has not been previously entered as to avoid any duplicate names. I have seen the inArray method and thought that the following code would tell me if it had found the value in an array?

```
if(jQuery.inArray(newName, nameArray) >= 0)
{
    alert("found");
}
else  //if -1
{
    alert("not found");
    classnameArrays.push(newClassName);
}
```

Would anyone be able to see what is wrong with the code. All i am trying to achieve is to have the name inserted into the array if their is no other name of the same value already present.

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Looks like you are checking `nameArray` and pushing into a different array `classnameArrays`

Comment: it's ok - http://jsfiddle.net/f3JkX/

Comment: As an aside, you'd be better of checking this kind of thing on the server.  In order to use javascript to check the registering user's name against all the other names, you'll obviously have to provide that data to javascript somehow (either by loading it with the page or AJAX it).  This exposes the name of every user in your database to the public - bad practice in terms of privacy.  Additionally, if you end up with thousands of users, this code would probably make the browser hang up while it looped through all those names - bad practice in terms of scalability. Do these checks server-side.

Answer (score 0):

That code is correct.

Could it be because you're checking to see if `newName` is in `nameArray`, but pushing `newClassName` into `classnameArrays`?

If you're still having trouble, install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) and use its debugger and interactive console to inspect the values you're dealing with. That usually helps me figure out this kind of problem.